# Ubuntu 14.04/Serverpilot running CGI Scripts

Tags: apache2, nginx, perl, cgi

Got an odd Serverpilot query.

My client wants FTP access to a subfolder on the site - loathe to let them have full access so created a user with access to `/home/FTPUSER` and symlink to this from my `/srv/users/serverpilot/apps/APPNAME/public/` folder so that they cannot access the system files for their main site, etc from a script.

PHP files from this folder are working fine but the client now wants to be able to run CGI/Perl scripts from this folder. I have tried following instructions at https://serverpilot.io/community/articles/how-to-create-a-cgi-bin-directory.html (updating the document root) but can't get CGI or Perl scripts to run, instead being returned as plain text.

Any thoughts?